# Tcl/Tk: "bad window path name" when it is not a window path

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have scripts which were used without Tk. When I added Tk one line is treated as path to window and I don't understand why.

Error infor is like:
`bad window path name "* Log directory: D:/tests/log/2016_10_13_17_30_29"`

It is when this line is executed:

```
message "* Log directory: ${dirname}"
```

`dirname` is resolved as path to directory, for example:

```
D:/tests/log/2016_10_13_17_30_29
```

`message` is a simple procedure for logging to file:

```
proc message {text} {
    global test_log_filename
    puts -nonewline $test_log_filename "[timestamp]         "
    puts $test_log_filename $text
}
```

When I do not use Tk it is working correctly. As I understand it takes `message` procedure argument as path to Tk window, but I don't know why. Of course such a window doesn't exist.

I also tried to invoke something like `message test` to confirm that it is argument problem. It gives error `bad window path name "test"`

Could you please help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tk *also* defines a command called `message` (it's a widget similar to a `label`, but with a somewhat different word-wrapping algorithm; it's not recommended for new code) and for some reason, that's winning out. While you could probably force yours to be used instead by directly `source`ing your code after the `package require Tk`, it's unlikely to be a good idea as you may find some other code breaks because of it. (I can't remember if it is currently used in the standard dialogs, but that's the sort of thing which might go wrong.)

The easiest thing is to change the name of your logging procedure. Perhaps to `Message` (with the capital letter). That shouldn't take long as it's effectively not much more than a global search-and-replace.